# How can I filter a map / Firestore Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to search for data from a map in the "users" collection of a single document. But I only found ways to search all documents.

See below.
Code 1:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
    Map<String, dynamic> res = doc["favorite"];
  });
});
```

Code 2:

```
final String _collection = 'users';
final FirebaseFirestore _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

getData() async {
  return await _fireStore.collection(_collection).get();
}

getData().then((val) {
  if (val.docs.length > 0) {
    print(val.docs[0].data()["favorite"]);
  } else {
    print("Not Found");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can search in fields:

```
// Create a reference to the cities collection
var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

// Create a query against the collection.
var query = citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA");
```

See the Firestore queries reference here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Don't work =/  Can't call var query = citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA");

Comment: Hello @Ruan what is the "favorite" field? You want to search all documents that have "favorite" equals to? What is the structure of your documents in Firestore?